# How to normalize scores of abstracts across different reviewers at an interdisciplinary symposium?

Tags: conference, abstract

For an interdisciplinary symposium: is it more fair to the participants to:

- Average scores of submitted abstracts across different reviewers?
- Estimate the overlap of the scientific domains between a participant and the reviewers, and weight different reviews accordingly? (which may introduce some bias)

(A detailed examination of reviewers is not possible. Reviewers are quite mixed, and come from different domains. Reviewers should be capable to judge most abstracts.)

Comment: To be honest, neither of the options you present sound particularly "fair".  In my field (computer science), it's fairly common to normalize review scores by looking at the distribution of scores for the 30-45 submissions each program committee member is responsible for.  Also, each reviewer is asked to rate their confidence/expertise in addition to rating the paper.

Comment: But in any case, I hope you're not basing your acceptance decisions on _scores_ but on the _content_ of the reviews.

Comment: it is indeed only an intermediate step

Comment: @JeffE Just playing Devil's advocate, but presumably rejection and acceptance is an implicit scoring of the abstract as 0 = reject or 1 = accept.